# jquery datatable : get selected check box rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have the following datatable. Its got a list of columns. Last column is a checkbox.

I want to get list of all rows which has the checkbox ticked? is it possible to get all datatable rows with the checkbox checked? my datatable is like below

```
    $.fn.dataTable.moment('DD.MM.YYYY');
    $('#bankReconDataListing tbody').off('click');
   RECON_DATATABLE = $('#bankReconDataListing').DataTable({
    "language": __DT,
    "select": true,
    "order": [
        [1, "desc"]
    ],
    "searchable": true,
    "destroy": true,
    "sAjaxSource": '/bankReconciliationGetData?coa=' + coa + '&toDate=' + toDate + '&fromDate=' + fromDate,
    "sAjaxDataProp": "",
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "pageLength": 20,
    "aoColumns": [{ //document date : 0
    "mDataProp": null,
    { //Document type  //5
        //balance
        "mDataProp": null,
        render: function(data, type, row) {
            return data.doctype;
        }
    },
    render: function(data, type, row) {
        return "<input type='checkbox' name='" + checkBoxName + "' data-tableinput='checkbox'  " +
            "id='checkBox" + reconJrnlId + "' value='" + reconJrnlId + "' checked='checked' />";

    }
}],
    "columnDefs": [],
    "initComplete": function() {}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a class name to your checkbox column, say checkboxclass.
Then,

```
  $('.checkboxclass:checked',table.fnGetNodes()).each(function(){
        //what you want to do 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could attach an event handler to the checkboxes in the table. Whenever a checkbox is clicked, that row gets added to an array. If it's unchecked, you remove it from the array.

This is untested but something like this should work:

```
let arr = [];

$("#tableDiv tbody").on("click", "input[type='checkbox']", function(e) {

    let row = $(this).closest('tr');

    // Get row data
    let data = table.row(row).data();

    if (this.checked) {

        // Add to array
        arr.push(data);

    } else {

        arr.splice(arr.indexOf(data), 1);

    }

});
```

`#tableDiv` is just the table's container. You could use whatever other selector is appropriate depending on your application.